# $f$ $n$ times continuously differentiable implies $f$ is integrable?

Tags: integration, derivatives

If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $n$ times continuously differentiable, then what does this imply about $f$'s integrability?

Reason, in my problem I'm given the assumption of $n$ times continuously differentiable and a subproblem defines the integral $g(x)=\int_x^{x_0} f(t)dt$. So it seems like $ƒ$ is integrable, but what's the connection between $n$ times continuously differentiable and integrable?

What about higher integrals?
Does this generalize to "$n$ times integrable"?

Comment: $f$ is differentiable at $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ $\implies$ $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ $\implies$ $f$ is integrable (over some closed $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$), because $f$ is a continuous function?

Comment: If a function $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then it is integrable over $[a,b]$.And a differentiable function is _a fortiori_ continuous.

Comment: And I believe this generalizes to $n$ times integrable, since $f$ integrable on $[a,b]$ $\implies$ $\int f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ $\implies$ $\int f$ is integrable $\implies$ $\int \int f$ is continuous $\implies$ $\cdot \cdot \cdot$

Answer (score 1):

We use Lebesgue's integrability condition.
From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability:

> A bounded function on a compact interval [a, b] is Riemann integrable if and only if it is continuous almost everywhere (..)

We only need continuity of $f$ here, which follows from continuously differentiable.
The first requirement is also fulfilled because a continuous function on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded.
So $f$ restricted to $[x, x_0]$ is bounded.